# Listeners do firebase database não é executado e não recupera dados, nem escreve - java server desktop

Tags: java, firebase-database, aplicação-desktop, realtime-database

Já tem alguns dias que estou tentando entender o que está acontecendo com o meu código que deveria escrever e ler no Firebase Realtime Database, mas sem sucesso e não há nenhum problema aparente, erro, exceção ou qualquer tipo de problema pra dar dica do que se passa. Eu estou codificando em java nativo, usado as orientações dá página do firebase admin, não é para Android como praticamente todas as ocorrências em minhas pesquisas retornam muito. Fiz um código também para o Android a mesma operação usando a mesma base de dados e funcionou perfeitamente, por isso não consigo entender o porque de estar dando errado e estou consumindo muito tempo e energia nisso e sem sucesso, se alguém puder ajudar, eu agradeceria muito!!

Como no Android é perfeitamente possível ler e gravar dados, descartei a possibilidade de o problema estar no banco de dados. Estou seguindo as instruções disponíveis na página do Firebase Admin, como dito antes, e também não há erro algumn, mas também não há resultado. Com a mesma configuração e o arquivo json com a key obtida da Firebase console, está funcionando corretamente com o Firebase Cloud Messaging, considerei que a chave também está correta, além de não ter erro ao rodar o código e ainda consigo recuperar dado pelo `DatabaseReference ref =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()`.

O código é este que segue abaixo, quase o mesmo da página do Firebase:

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class StarterFRD {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream refreshToken = new FileInputStream("/Users/wdcunha/Development/Java/frdproj/src/main/resources/housecontrolmobile-firebase-adminsdk-qv0hl-f41a07409d.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(refreshToken))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://housecontrolmobile.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

     // As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("users");

        System.out.println("ref: "+ref);

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Object document = dataSnapshot.getValue();
                System.out.println("document: "+document);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                System.out.println("canceled: "+error.toException());
            }
        });

        Utilizador utilz = new Utilizador("Euquipe", "eu@quipe.com");

        System.out.println("utilz nome: "+utilz.getNome());
        System.out.println("utilz email: "+utilz.getEmail());

        ref.child("2").push().setValueAsync(utilz);

        ref.child("3").setValue("I'm writing data", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    System.out.println("Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Data saved successfully."+databaseReference);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

{[image: base de dados (json) esta (link aqui)].

Se alguém puder dar uma ajuda com essa questão, agradeço muito, pois não consegui achar nada que pudesse dar uma luz pra esse problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava em não ficar aberta sessão como a de um server. Estava executando o código e ao atingir o final dele, era encerrado, de forma que não dava tempo de obter a resposta do firebase. Quando então coloquei sua execução num server, foi possível ver a resposta que precisava. Simples, mas me tomou muito tempo precioso. Caso alguém passe pelo mesmo, lembre-se que se trata de comando assíncrono e também que dependem da conexão e não vai ser retornado de imediato, portanto precisa de manter o código rodando.

Answer (score 0):

ele esta te retornando uma List voce ta pegando como se fosse um objeto so!
tem que fazer um for

```
for(DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapShot.getValues()){
    Usuario user = snap.getValue(Usuario.class); // Classe usuario tem que estar igual aos dados do firebase, no caso ali email e nome, e adiciona aos dados ali o id tambem
}
```

id
email
nome

quando for gravar no realtime, grava o id tambem nos dados.

Comment: apesar de o problema ter sido o que relatei acima, agradeço pela sugestão Daniel Sampaio!